# Cordova: read file received as intent

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a cordova application for android, and I want to be able to receive files via share menu and import them into my app.

I'm using the following cordova plugin: https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent. It is the only one I found that allows you to handle intents in a way that is useful for the task that I want: appear on the share with menu.

Everything works fine when sharing text snippets (text selections, youtube links, chrome links...) but I don't know how to import a file that has been shared with me. I tried opening the file with the regular methods, but that reports null content, which I think is because I don't have permissions to access the file on its location.

So, how can I read directly from the intent that is sent to me?

Here is a tutorial that I followed to setup my application:

http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/101/how-to-list-your-cordova-app-in-open-with-menu-in-android-and-handle-the-intent-event

But it lacks the part about how to access the shared file. The data model that is received as intent is similar to this:

```
{
    "action": "android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE",
    "clipItems": [
        {
            "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/example-document.pdf",
            "type": "application/pdf",
            "extension": "pdf"
        },
        {
            "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/example-archive.zip",
            "type": "application/zip",
            "extension": "zip"
        }
        {
            "uri": "content://media/external/images/media/29",
            "type": "image/jpeg",
            "extension": "jpeg"
        }

    ],
    "flags": 390070273,
    "type": "*/*",
    "component": "ComponentInfo{com.example.droid/com.example.droid.MainActivity}",
    "extras": "Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=596]"
}
```

**INVESTIGATION UPDATE**

Checking the java code of the plugin that I'm using, I found a method that gets a contentResolver ([line 233](https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent/blob/master/src/android/IntentPlugin.java#L233)), which can be used to get a  ParcelFileDescriptor which in turn can be used to get a FileDescriptor which can be used to read the file according to [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/request-file.html)

I'm not sure if I can use another cordova plugin to read the file having the uri or if I have to implement my own method to read from that uri.

Any advice is very welcome

Comment: `read file received as intent`. You mean: "read a file when file name or content scheme of file received with intent"!?

Comment: When you click the share button on a file explorer, and select the target application that application receives an intent with some uri and other references about the file that is being shared. I don't know how to access that file from my app

Comment: Edited the question to clarify a bit

Comment: Just show the code where you receive and decode the intent.

Comment: It is unclear what problems you have exactly. If you receive `"uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/example-document.pdf". Then you can extract `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/example-document.pdf` ? And having this file path you don't know how to open the file? All unclear.

Comment: `The data model that is received as intent is similar to this:`. Strange. That looks like Json. Better show what you really receive. You don't receive a model but an intent.

Comment: Dear greenapps, maybe you are thinking about this like a java/android specific thing? Note that I'm using cordova an accessing the intents through a plugin that makes them available to javascript. I don't have any java experience, but maybe checking the source of the library that I posted give us a clue about what I'm actually getting

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` from plugin *cordova-plugin-file* to get the **fileEntry** and then file handle which you can later read using *file-reader.*